# jQuery - scope within an "each"?

Tags: jquery, each

I have three td's and am trying to limit the function inside **each** to only that td. How do I do this? With this code, it's taking *all 3 images* and inserting all of them before the h2:

```
jQuery("td.frontpage_news").each(function() {
    jQuery("span.frontpage_news p:first-child").has("a img").insertBefore("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news");      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get the element currently being processed by the `each` - using that object in conjunction with [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will allow you to scope your calls:

```
jQuery("td.frontpage_news").each(function() {
    var $that = jQuery(this);
    var $thatHeading = $that.find("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news");
    $that.find("span.frontpage_news p:first-child")
         .has("a img").insertBefore( $thatHeading  );
});
```

This assumes that the content heading and front page news items are children of the td.

Comment: It's still inserting before all h2's. Can I do the same $this to limit the h2? something like `insertBefore(this).find("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news");`

Comment: I think your latest code worked. I tried this inside the 'each': `jQuery(this).find("span.frontpage_news p:first-child").has("a img").insertBefore(this).find("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news");   
`  , but it was inserting it a level above the h2 (sibling to the td) for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using each.
Just use this:

```
jQuery("td.frontpage_news span.frontpage_news p:first-child").has("a img").insertBefore("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news");
```

If you really need to use an each then provide the `this` context to jquery to search withn

```
jQuery("td.frontpage_news").each(function() {
    jQuery("span.frontpage_news p:first-child", this).has("a img").insertBefore("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news");      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("h2.contentheading.frontpage_news").before(jQuery("td.frontpage_news span.frontpage_news p:first-child").has("a img"));
```